# How to reference a variable inside an exports function?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Novice question: I have a bunch of variables defined inside an exports function, for example:

```
var movies;

function Tabs(Window) {
    //create module instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
        activeTabIconTint: '#F4CA53',
        tabsBackgroundColor: '#000000'
    });

     movies = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: movieData,
    });

  return self;
}

module.exports = Tabs;
```

Then over in another js file, that is included in scope, I'm trying to reference that movies variable (tableview). I have tried different things and nothing works:

```
movies.setData(movieData);
Tabs.movies.setData(movieData);
```

How can I update the "data" property of the "movies" tableview when I am outside the "Tabs" function?

Comment: try changing `module.exports = Tabs;` with `exports.Tabs = Tabs;` and `exports.movies = movies;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just pass it to the Tabs function?

```
function Tabs(Window, movieData) {
    //create module instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
        activeTabIconTint: '#F4CA53',
        tabsBackgroundColor: '#000000'
    });

     movies = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: movieData,
    });

  return self;
}

module.exports = Tabs;

//then call it like:
Tabs(window, movieData);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that movieData needs to change many times over the lifecycle of the app, long after Tabs has been instantiated. So I need to reach back in and change movieData several times, later. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
var movies;

function _getMovies() { return movies; }

function _setMovies(_value) { movies = _value; }

function _Tabs(Window) {
    //create module instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
        activeTabIconTint: '#F4CA53',
        tabsBackgroundColor: '#000000'
    });

     movies = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        data: movieData,
    });

  return self;
}

module.exports = {
    Tabs : _Tabs,
    getMovies : _getMovies,
    setMovies : _setMovies,
}
```

then require the tabs file

```
var myTab = require('myTab);

myTab.Tabs(aWindow)

var localMovies = myTab.getMovies();
```